# How to move to next page after removing current page from stack in ionic 2?

Tags: cordova, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want functionality like android's finish() method. I have a splash image page. After it loads I move to home page after 1.5 secs. But when I do that I want the splash page to be first removed from the stack so that the home page doesn't have it to go back to.

How can this be done?

Comment: Could you check this [link](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/).

Comment: generally [splashscreen](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/splashscreen/) is used and not a separate page. just call show/hide in app.component.ts.

Comment: To both of you above! Thanks for replying but i need to know the concept so that it can be used on other pages as well. Splashscreen was just for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the [doc](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/). Ionic 2 use its own nav module, but not router of angular2. NavController has a `pop()` function to  remove a page from stack.

Comment: I know you can pop page from stack also you can remove using an index value. But the point is to close the current page and then move to the next one so that the next page won't go back to the page we started from.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [remove](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/#remove) function to remove the previous page from the stack in `ngOnInit` of the new page which is pushed.

`this.navCtrl.remove()`

Or

If you mean to start a new stack, you can do `setRoot` instead of `push`.It would be possible solution for splash screen page to home.

Comment: I'm gonna try this. But will be better is to remove the page before the second is pushed so that the decision is taken in the first page only.